# How can I insert all values of one HashSet into another HashSet?

Tags: rust, union, hashset

I have two `HashSet<u16>`s and I would like to implement `a = a U b`. If possible, I'd like to use `HashSet::union` rather than loops or other tweaks.

I tried the following:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;
let mut a: HashSet<u16> = [1, 2, 3].iter().cloned().collect();
let b: HashSet<u16> = [7, 8, 9].iter().cloned().collect();  

// I can build a union object that contains &u16
let union: HashSet<&u16> = a.union(&b).collect();

// But I can't store the union into a
a = a.union(&b).collect();   //  -> compile error

// of course I can do
for x in &b {
    a.insert(*x);
}
// but I wonder if union could not be used to simply build a union
```

The error message is the following:

```
the trait bound 
`std::collections::HashSet<u16>: std::iter::FromIterator<&u16>`
is not satisfied
```

How can I perform `a = a U b`?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You don't want `union` — as you said, it will create a new `HashSet`. Instead you can use [`Extend::extend`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#tymethod.extend):

```rust
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let mut a: HashSet<u16> = [1, 2, 3].iter().copied().collect();
    let b: HashSet<u16> = [1, 3, 7, 8, 9].iter().copied().collect();

    a.extend(&b);

    println!("{:?}", a); // {8, 3, 2, 1, 7, 9}
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fd015567dc2e4d28b7d50a7ce2967a60))

`Extend::extend` is also [implemented for other collections](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Extend.html#implementors), e.g. `Vec`. The result for `Vec` will differ because `Vec` does not honor duplicates in the same way a `Set` does.

Comment: Great, exactly what I was looking for. Plus it teaches me that I should not only look at the 'methods' section of the doc to find methods, but also into the traits a struct implements. Rust is really a world on its own :-)

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> // But I can't store the union into a
> a = a.union(&b).collect();   //  -> compile error
> ```
>
> The error message is the following:
>
> ```
> the trait bound  `std::collections::HashSet<u16>:
> std::iter::FromIterator<&u16>` is not satisfied
> ```

It's because `a` is a `HashSet<u16>`, but `a.union(&b)` is an `Iterator<Item=&u16>`. Converting `a.union(&b)` to `Iterator<Item=u16>` by using `.copied()` works:

```
a = a.union(&b).copied().collect(); // compiles
```

As the other mentioned, this will create a new `HashSet`. In some cases, this might be what you want, but it will make more sense if it's assigned to another variable:

```
let c: HashSet<u16> = a.union(&b).copied().collect();

// a is unchanged here
```

Answer (score 0):

For collecting multiple hashsets:

```
use std::collections::HashSet;

fn main() {
    let a: HashSet<u16> = [1, 2, 3].iter().copied().collect();
    let b: HashSet<u16> = [1, 3, 7, 8, 9].iter().copied().collect();
    let all = [a,b];
    let combined = all.iter().flatten().collect::<HashSet<_>>();

    println!("{:?}", combined);
}
```

Playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=44cd73eb3a4e628378cbb7ff11a32649